# iPhone setDelegate to a previously allocated object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I'm trying to set up protocols and delegation.

I have a problem tho that i wish to set a delegate to a previously allocated object.

The object i am allocating needs to delegate to a protocol. how is this done?

Heres my code.

//SendSMS.h

```
@protocol ModalViewDelegate

- (void)didReceiveMessage:(NSString *)message;

@end

@interface SendSMS : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> {


    MessageOptions *messageOptions;
    LoginPage *loginPage;
    IBOutlet UITextField *phonenumber;
    IBOutlet UITextView *smsBody;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollview;

}

-(IBAction)LoadMessageOptions;

@end
```

The problem is when the object is pushed onto the stack. Its delegate isn't that of its self. but that of the object before it.

Any ideas?

UPDATE!

Ok i have managed to set my delegate to `[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]` which is the rootviewcontroller. But i have 3 complier warnings stating that the methods are not found in the protocols. Which they are.... But it compiles runs and works.

Comment: In the class where you create it you can assign the delegate as the object implementing the protocol. Check http://www.iprav.in/?p=57

Comment: i did but it sets delegate to self. I can't delegate to self because I have 3 views and want view 3 to pass data to view 1. it would be pointless passing through to self twice if i can skip it out, which is what i did but getting the controller where the methods are set off the stack.

Comment: If you have reference to view1 or its controller then when you create view3 assign the delegate to that reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never let an instance set the delegate unto itself. The whole idea with delegates is that you should not need to know who the delegate is. As I understand your architecture it is three levels deep;

1. `View1` is the root controller, it creates and pushes;
2. `View2` that do some stuff and then creates and pushes;
3. `View3` that wants to send some results to whoever is concerned.

I see two possible solutions.

**Solution 1 - Delegates**

1. Let `View3` declare a delegate protocol `View3Delegate`.
2. Let `View1` conform to `View3Delegate`.
3. When `View1` creates and pushes `View2` also pass it `self` to hold on to.
4. When `View2` creates and pushes `View3` also set the delegate that was passed in step 3.
5. When `View3` wants to send it's result, call the delegate and be happy.

**Solution 2 - Notifications**

This is probably a more elegant solution in your case, since the previous solution has an extra step where `View2` needs to handle stuff just in order to make `View1` and `View3` work, not related to it's real responsibilities.

1. Let `View3` declare a notification named `View3ResponseNotification`.
2. Let `View1` observe notifications of the name `View3ResponseNotification`.
3. `View1` creates and pushes `View2` with no worries.
4. `View2` creates and pushes `View3` with no worries.
5. When `View3` wants to send it's results it posts the `View3ResponseNotification` notification.

Comment: i'll give you the tick. this was the way i thought of doing it but i thought it to be a bit lengthy. so when the View 2 pushes the View 3. it setsthedelegate to the viewcontroller at index:0 in the stack. It works really well. The problems i was having above were yet another xcode problem where a simple reboot stopped the compiler warnings.